# Upload file via $_FILES or php://input? Which is better on the system?

Tags: php, ios, server

I am creating a script that via my iOS application I can upload a file. I was wondering which method is better or safer for the system? `$_FILES` or `php://input`? Does it matter? I am curious to know because users will need to upload multiple files at once, for example one user may upload one photo but 10k are doing it at once. I am just trying to prepare for a situation like that.

Any suggestions on this? I know `$_FILES` writes to the temp directory, I believe `php://input` does not though (does it use system memory)? Please help me understand. I found a few other threads on this but nothing specifically said how it affects the system & which one is better for my situation.

The files will not be bigger than 2MB at most.

Comment: Using `php://input` would mean that you would need to handle the incoming `multipart/form-data` encoding yourself (dealing with boundaries, content-types, etc.) – whereas using `$_FILES`, PHP handles all that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whichever you choose, php will always have the entire file in memory due to the way php handles file uploads.

I'd stick with `$_FILES`, it's already there to help you with the handling of file uploads with PHP.